# update Array field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I can't find a way to update a mongoDB field which is an array of strings. I have this service on frontend

> foodService.ts

```
updateSheet(id: string, foods: any) {
console.log('from service', id, foods);
return this.http.post<BreedingSheet>(`${this.breedingSheetsUrl}/${id}`, foods);
}
```

**It console.logs :**

from service *60cfb5ad65462f00158c38d9*

{food1: "meat",food2: "mushrooms"}

so everything looks fine to me so far.

and on backend I have this

```
router.post('/:id', async(req, res, next) => {
console.log('DATA ID', req.params.id);
console.log('DATA FOODS', req.body.foods);
const updateSheet = await BreedingSheet.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, {foods: 
req.body.foods},
(error, sheet) => {
  if(error) {
    return console.log('error while updating');
  }
  return res.status(200).json({sheet});
})
});
```

**the console.log gives me:**

DATA ID 60cfb5ad65462f00158c38d9

DATA FOODS undefined

From backend model:

```
  foods: { type:[], required: true }
```

and from frontend model:

```
  foods: string[];
```

The question is why am I getting ***undefined*** from backend on foods (req.body.foods)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter of `post` is body so if you want to get your foods by `req.body.foods`, you need to pass it in this way:

```
this.http.post<BreedingSheet>(`${this.breedingSheetsUrl}/${id}`, { foods })
```

Comment: i tried your { foods } it pass correctly but it puts an object into my mongoDB array. i also changed const foods = {
        food1 : this.foodOne.value,
        food2: this.foodTwo?.value,
        food3: this.foodThree?.value
      };

to

const foods = [
        this.foodOne.value,
        this.foodTwo?.value,
        this.foodThree?.value
      ];

But it gives me an array inside my array so it's not working as i excepted.

Comment: Can you show the updated document after change foods to array?

Comment: Yes, in mongoDB i had before update : ["meat", "seeds"] and after update i have [ ["meat", "vegetables"] ]
So an array in an array. any way to have the updated document like ["meat", "vegetables"] instead ?

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(req.body.foods)`? Is it `["meat", "seeds"] ` or `[ ["meat", "seeds"] ]`

Comment: the result of console log is ["meat", "seeds"]

Comment: That's weird. Can you show your full model file? And do you use any operator like `$push`?